# Representation of complex numbers in C++ for Discrete Fourier Transformation

Tags: c++, math, stl, fft, complex-numbers

I am currently writing a small tool which should help me check whether my manually calculated fourier vectors are correct. Now i need the n-th Root of Unity specified by `omega = exp(2*pi*i / n)`. Can somebody explain me how to represent this `omega` as a `complex` in C++?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Euler's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):

```
exp(2πi/n) = cos(2π/n) + i sin(2π/n)
```

Then it's easy:

```
complex<double> rootOfUnity(cos(TWOPI/n), sin(TWOPI/n));
```

(replace TWOPI with either a macro available on your system or just the value of 2π however you see fit).

Comment: Any specific suggestion how to compute pi? Would ``4*atan(1.0)`` suffice?

Comment: Using Visual Studio 2010 on Windows 8 with Microsofts C++ Compiler. Including ``cmath.h`` does not provide ``M_PI``!

Comment: @Christian: yes, using 4.0*atan(1.0) will work fine.  Or you can just use `double TWOPI = 6.283185307179586476925286766559`.

Comment: @Christian: I didn't realize that! :) Because I always define my own Pi macro hard-coded to 50 some digits... lol

Comment: I am just wondering how i know this atan'thingy but forgot the Euler Formula :) Thanks, folks!

Comment: `#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES` before including `cmath` or `math.h` to get M_PI and friends. This is Visual Studio specific: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4hwaceh6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Well, the real and imaginary parts of the twiddle factor omega is just:

```
double angle = 2*pi/n;

double real = cos(angle);
double imaj = sin(angle);

complex<double> omega(real, imaj);
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a function that returns a complex number using polar coordinates:

```
#include<complex>
complex polar(const T& rho)
complex polar(const T& rho, const T& theta)
```

where `rho` is the magnitude, and `theta` is the angle in radians.

In this case, `rho` is always 1.0.

```
const double pi = 3.141592653589793238462643383279;
double omega = polar(1.0, 2*pi*i/n);
```